# How to fix prime check/factorization function

Tags: python

I'm playing around to learn python. I want to create a module to check for primes and factorize a given number. But importing the module causes the factors to appear as often as I run the code.
When I run the imported function like 3 times I get the result: "60 is not prime. Its factors are: [2, 2, 3, 5, 2, 2, 3, 5, 2, 2, 3, 5]"

I think the problem is that I define the array prime_factors before the functions. 
When I try to put the array into the function it just gives: "x is not prime. Its factors are: []", where x is the number I wanted to check.

```
prime_factors=[]

def factorize(x):
    i=2  
    while i <= x:
        if x%i==0:
            x=x/i
            prime_factors.append(i)
        else:
            i+=1


def prime_check(x):
    import numpy as np
    factorize(x)
    if np.size(prime_factors)==1:
        print(str(x)+" is prime.")
    else:
        print(str(x)+" is not prime. Its factors are: "+str(prime_factors))
```

I just wanted an output such as: "60 is not prime. Its factors are: [2, 2, 3, 5]" for the prime-checker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is right. This will work (with some spacing edits for clarity):

```
def factorize(x):
    prime_factors = []
    i = 2  
    while i <= x:
        if x % i == 0:
            x /= i
            prime_factors.append(i)
        else:
            i += 1
    return prime_factors
```

As a general principle, your function should not modify variables outside its scope unless there is a good reason. It is much better practice to return something, rather than modify a global variable.

Comment: Thank you very much. By changing the prime_factors-array in the code of the prime_check-function to utilize the factorization function I now get the proper results! Helped a lot.